# Compare Two Byte Arrays & Get The Percentage in Java?

Tags: java, compare, arrays

We want to create A system in Java Programming Language to compare two audio files and get the percentage of the Comparison. The files is being converted into fingerprints as byte arrays.

Can anyone help me to give a solution to compare two byte arrays and get the similarity as a percentage?

Comment: *Comparison* meaning byte by byte comparison and *percentage* is the ratio of unequal bytes? Btw, there is no need to go capslock and multi-punctuation on us. ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? The difficulty is on obtaining the PCM samples of the audio, or on the algorithm for comparison?

Comment: Comparing at the individual sample level is going to produce a solid zero for anything other than identical files. Or rather, the value is going to be as if random pairs of `short` were being compared.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That depends on their feature generation (fingerprints). If they have a low resolution, you can actually easily match features, that would not be equal in high resolution features.

Comment: We are using 'musicg' [link](https://sites.google.com/site/musicgapi/)  as the Fingerprint Generator. We are stuck at the Comparison Part???

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the comparison? As I see it, the *musicg-api* already provides methods to do [fingerprint recognition](https://sites.google.com/site/musicgapi/User-guide-v1-4-x/fingerprint-recognition) and there is also a `Wave #getFingerprintSimilarity(Wave)` method present. *And again: No need for multi-punctuation.*

Answer (score 3):

```
/** Returns percentage (0.0-100.0) of not matching bytes. If arrays are not of equal length, nonexisting bytes in the smaller array will be treated as not matching. */
public double compareByteArrays(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
  int n = Math.min(a.length, b.length), nLarge = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
  int unequalCount = nLarge - n;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    if (a[i] != b[i]) unequalCount++;
  return unequalCount * 100.0 / nLarge;
}
```

This would actually just compare the bytes itself (as asked in the title). You could also do some sort of distance between your two vectors (distance in feature space). Or you could do one of a million other things that you can find on [google scholar](http://scholar.google.com)...

EDIT: You told us that you use the *musicg-api*, therefore you can compare different Waves like this:

```
String track1 = "track1.wav", track2 = "track2.wav";
Wave wave1 = new Wave(track1), wave2 = new Wave(track2);

FingerprintSimilarity similarity;

// compare fingerprints:
similarity = wave1.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave2);
System.out.println("clip is found at "
                + similarity.getsetMostSimilarTimePosition() + "s in "
                + song1+" with similarity " + similarity.getSimilarity());
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. We are using 'musicg'link as our Fingerprint Generator. The part we are stuck is how to compare the generated fingerprint of the audio file with another generated Fingerprint. The fingerprint we are getting is A Byte Array.

Comment: @brimborium:  If you have used musicg-api please respond to original question, as I am in the same limbo. Using musicg-api, If I get fingerprint of two wave files, is there a way (using musicg-api or regular java or else) to determine the similarity factor? Thank you.

Comment: @MehdiAnis I have not used musicg-api so far. But there are plenty of examples on their page. You just have to read it... ;)

Comment: @brimborium: musicg-API site did not have a direct example of using fingerprint to find similarity. But, I read the source code and found the function that does the job. I have posted the answer above. Reading does help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using musicg API. You have to use the `Wave` objects, not their fingerprints but if you can generate fingerprints you can get the `Wave` object easily.

```
Wave waveA = ...
Wave waveB = ...
FingerprintSimilarity similarity;
similarity = waveA.getFingerprintSimilarity(waveB);
float result = similarity.getSimilarity();
```

`result` is the similarity as a float. Multiply by 100 to get a percentage

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. We are using 'musicg'[link](https://sites.google.com/site/musicgapi/) as our Fingerprint Generator. The part we are stuck is how to compare the generated fingerprint of the audio file with another generated Fingerprint. The fingerprint we are getting is A Byte Array.

Comment: @DinishaTennakoon You can reward helpful answers by voting them up and accepting the best answer (the one that helped you the most). Use the gray up arrow and the checkmark to do so. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found the function to compare two wave files by their fingerprints. The musicg-api function that does the job is = FingerprintSimilarityComputer

Here is my C# code, but you get the JAVA idea too:

```
public static int MatchFingerPrint(Byte[] SuspectFingerPrint, Byte[] SampleFingerPrint)
        {

            FingerprintSimilarityComputer fpComputer = new FingerprintSimilarityComputer(SuspectFingerPrint, SampleFingerPrint);
            FingerprintSimilarity fpmSimilarity = fpComputer.getFingerprintsSimilarity();
            return (int)(fpmSimilarity.getScore()*100.0f);
        }
```

Comment: where is the library?